# Align 4 columns in a row centered and responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 columns that I'm trying to align centered in a row and have them be responsive when it goes mobile with Bootstrap 4, but I'm having some problems getting them to align properly. I want some space between the columns as shown below, but I also want them to stay in a row and not stack.

Here is what it's currently doing:
[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.row-centered {
    text-align:center;
    display: inherit;
}
#businessDevTitle {
    text-align: left;
}
.col-centered {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    /* reset the text-align */
    text-align:left;
    /* inline-block space fix */
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="ttr_main" class="row row-centered">
<h3 id="businessDevTitle">Business Development</h3>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
        <div class="col-*">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zDpdA1M.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
        <div class="col-*">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1sjJ136.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
        <div class="col-*">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jaIojmI.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
        <div class="col-*">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CKd16El.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using bootstrap here we will try to achieve that by classes provided by bootstrap so in that way less custom CSS will be needed.

Structure your HTML in the following way:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="ttr_main" class="row">
        <h3 id="businessDevTitle">Business Development</h3>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zDpdA1M.png" class="img-responsive centered"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1sjJ136.png" class="img-responsive centered"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jaIojmI.png" class="img-responsive centered"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CKd16El.png" class="img-responsive centered"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and discard the css for `col-centered` and `row-centered` and just add this class:

```
.centered {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work sadly. I do appreciate the input.

Comment: Check out the fiddle here is the working solution https://jsfiddle.net/aditi17/5m128sv6/. Could you please explain what's wrong with that or where it does not meet your requirement so I could better help.